# Erased both partitions of my hard drive and want to merge them. They show up as two different disks so I cant choose the partition option

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

External hard drive partitions showing as 2 different disks, can't merge or repartition. I have erased both and want to merge into one.

EDIT: I have Reformatted both partitions to Mac OS Extended (Journaled) but still have the same problem.

macOS Mojave Version 10.14.4

[image: Diskur1 and Diskur2 are on the same hard drive]

Comment: Yes, when I do that they both show under the same physical drive. I was able to choose the parent drive after clicking "Show all devices" and then doing a master boot record. Thanks!

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257994/119271) on how to repartition the USB drive

Comment: Great, I have added it as an answer, if you could accept that all will be right in the world of AskDifferent guidelines! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In Disk Utility go to the View menu and select

"Show all devices."

That should then show those two partitions under the "parent" physical drive mand allow you to repartition.